How to delete data on disk immediately after drop table on Attu?
Are there any settings on how to delete data on disk immediately after drop table on Attu?
And we have another question, we found the 'Appro Entity Count' on the Attu has not increased for some time, but index_files on disk are still creating, cause Attu only counts the data of the index that has already been built? Is there any other way to count the amount of data that has already been indexed?

1.Milvus has garbage collection machinery, it is a background thread to trigger gc for each hour. The default interval to trigger gc is 1 hour, which is defined in the milvus.yaml:
dataCoord:
  gc:
    interval: 3600 # gc interval in seconds
    missingTolerance: 86400 # file meta missing tolerance duration in seconds, default to 24hr(1d)
    dropTolerance: 10800 # file belongs to dropped entity tolerance duration in seconds. 3600
    removeConcurrent: 32 # number of concurrent goroutines to remove dropped s3 objects
    scanInterval: 168 # garbage collection scan residue interval in hours

When you drop a collection, its data is not deleted immediately from storage. They will be kept in storage for 1 ~ 3 hours.
2.The 'Approx Entity Count' is equal to the 'collection.num_entities' in pymilvus. This method quickly pick the number from Etcd.
As we know, when you insert data, the data firstly is passed to the Pulsar(or local message queue) as write-ahead-log. And the query nodes and data nodes consume the data from the message queue. Data node accumulates data in an in-memory buffer, once the buffer size exceeds a threshold, data node flushes the buffer to be sealed segment.
Only sealed segments are recorded in Etcd. This method only counts the number of rows in sealed segments. Some data maight still in message queue or in the buffer of data node. So, this method is inaccurate. And, this method doesn't count the deleted items.
The accurate way is: https://milvus.io/docs/get-and-scalar-query.md#Advanced-operators
In pymilvus:
res = client.query(collection_name=name, filter="", output_fields=["count(*)"])
print(f'row count: {res[0]["count(*)"]}')

It is a real query to iterate all the segments including the in-memory buffer to sum up the row count, and deleted items are skipped.
In Attu, if you click load button to load the collection, it will call query(count(*)) to get the accurate row count and show the number in the 'Approx Entity Count' field.
Get & Scalar Query | Milvus Documentation
